# Java GUI dynamic text with editable delimiters

Tags: java, user-interface, text, delimiter

First of all, I don't know how to exactly formulate my question, so I don't know what to search for, really. If you know what I mean and it has a name, or even an answer somewhere, feel free to tell me.

I want to segment texts (into sentences or sentence-like structures) and show the segments to the user, with delimiters (*extends JComponent*) after each segment. Since the segmentation won't always fit, the user should then have the possibility to delete delimiters and insert new ones, but the text itself should not really be editable.

The question is, how (by what class or structure) should I display the text and delimiters so that the structure, but not the text itself is editable?

Any suggestions?

What I'm trying to do:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Can you create images of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels (http://s16.postimage.org/docu3v4yt/textdelim.png) Here is a crappy paint image. I hope it gets the point across.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't have much of a clue. :(